# Upgrade to yocto 2.4 vmdk is no longer a image type

Tags: yocto

I was building a vmware vmdk in Pryo but wanting to add open-vm-tools. I upgraded to Rocko but now my image script says IMAGE_FSTYPE = "vmdk" is not valid. The release notes says they are changing it to a conversion type. But everything i have tried doesn't create a vmdk or if I change FSTYPES to "wic.vmdk" it fails saying there is no files in the WIC_FILES.

How can i create a vmdk again in yocto 2.4?

Comment: Have you added "wic.vmdk" to `FSTYPES` variable or to `IMAGE_FSTYPES` variable? You need `IMAGE_FSTYPES += "wic.vmdk" `

Comment: Maybe try to add another type ` IMAGE_FSTYPE = "hdddirect vmdk"` ?